# Saving methods to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a browser-based RPG, and I want to be able to calculate a property of an object in different ways, based on another objects attributes.

More specifically. I have a Unit model with attributes such as health, strength, defence etc..

And I want to have a separate Skill model where each instance supplies a different way to calculate the total damage of the skill, based on the units attributes.

Example.

Fireball:

```
total_damage = unit.intelligence * 2 + 5
```

Throw Axe:

```
total_damage = unit.strength + unit.precision
```

How would i store this in a database effectively?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just calculate those fields on the fly and if you search for performance use memoization?

Comment: because many different units may use the same skill, but to varying effect

Comment: They might use the same skill but the calculation for every unit is unique to the unit.

Comment: but where would i store each different calculation

Comment: Just keep, for example `total_damage`, in the model as a method, which can be memoized.

Comment: Yes but how, I might have 100 different "total_damage" methods

Comment: Tarlen, I would create as many classes as units you might have. Have a Unit parent class, and make the other inherit from it. Define that method for each unit in its own class. Now it might be just this method, later on it might be the method that make your units walk that can vary.

Comment: That what my idea too, but would it be considered good style to perhaps having 100 different classes of units?

Comment: I don't think it would as long as the difference between those classes is only in the expression that evaluates total damage. When the differences start growing bigger, you will have to re-evaluate the hierarchy - make it multi-layered, for example, and branch out for every significant behaviour change.

Answer (score 0):

If the multitude of those variations is as great as you say, then look into expressions parsers, for example https://github.com/rubysolo/dentaku

Supply into each expression only the list of variables you think it might use and evaluate it. Expressions can of course be stored in a database.

Remember, that it will have certain performance overhead.

Answer (score 0):

For the way you describe your scenario, it seems to me that your different kind of units will **share the same attributes** but need **different behavior**. That's a good fit for Single Table Inheritance. Notice that right now it might just be the `total_damage` that is calculated differently for each kind of Unit, but later on it might be that you want your different Units to walk different. An Elephant unit will walk slowly than a Scout for example.

Say you already have a Unit model. You want to add a type column in that `Units` table. That column will specify the `kind` of Unit.

Your models should look now like this:

```
class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  def total_damage
  end
end

class Chariot < Unit
  def total_damage
    # Whatever damage a chariot can do!
  end
end

class Scout < Unit
  def total_damage
    # Whatever damage a scout can do!
  end
end
```

STI is a good approach if all your submodels are supposed to share the same attributes. If you think you will have 20 columns only used by one submodel, you might want to create different tables.